# How do I send data from Javascript to python in this instance?

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I coded a simple blackjack game based on Javascript and HTMl5, but I would like to send data from the game to my python code.

I am currently utilizing Flask to create the web app version of blackjack, but I am confused on how I can relay information from blackjack to python when the player wins.

Ie. After the Player wins the hand, From the JS code, send the python code "won", 
from here my Python code can add the winnings amount to the players total and save this in the mongo database. From here refresh the blackjack page.

JS code function:

```
if (dealerTotal > 21) {
  $("#message").html('Dealer Bust!');

  clearInterval(keepDealing);
  /// Pay up
  var bet = $("#bet").html();
  var money = $("#money").html();
  var winnings = bet * 2;
}

if (dealerTotal >= 17) {
  /// You Win
  if (playerTotal > dealerTotal) {

    $("#message").html('You Win!');

    /// Pay up
    var bet = $("#bet").html();
    var money = $("#money").html();
    var winnings = bet * 2; **
    How to relay winnings to python **

  }

  /// You Lose
  if (playerTotal < dealerTotal) {

    $("#message").html('You Lose!');
    /// Pay up
    var bet = $("#bet").html();
    var money = $("#money").html();
    var winnings = 0; **
    How to relay winnings to python **
  }

  if (playerTotal == dealerTotal) {
    //I can work on this later.
  }
}
```

All my python code does is need a way to accept a javascript input.
For example html form inputs are accepted in flask as `request.form['whatever']` but how would I accept a javascript variable.

If there is anything to be clarified please let me know

Thanks

Comment: Do you want the users to see the screen change/refresh when this happens, or do you want it to look like the screen just keeps on trucking?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would manifest a json file which the javascript could upload its data to and python could read it from. This method is probably not the most efficient but has more capability (such as storing the data and analyzation) than others.

-Ryan

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are using Flask.You can use Ajax in jquery to post to that endpoint and then at that point You have to specify the

```
@app.route("/end-point")
def endpoint():
    if request.is_xhr:
        #specify what input you want to get from request.form['whatever']
```

and in ajax part with jquery, use

```
$.ajax({
url: "/end-point"
method:method // where method is POST, GET, PUT or any tou want
data: formData

})
```

If you have any further question let me know in comments